# Uploading animated GIF outputs only first frame

Tags: assets, image-transforms

I've updated everything to the latest version and the result of uploading an animated GIF is just the first frame of the animated GIF.

Any ideas on why animated GIFs aren't working? Is there a way to disable image transforms for animated GIFs or GIFs in general?

- PHP 5.4.45-0+deb7u1
- ImageMagick 6.7.7-10
- Craft Pro 2.4.2692

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your [ImageMagick library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) version is 3.5 years old.  I'd start by updating that to something newer.

You didn't list the PHP Imagick extension version, but I'd bet it's out of date as well.  [3.1.2](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) is the latest stable release.

Also, Craft will automatically try and detect if Imagick is installed and available via PHP, but it won't hurt to explicitly set the [imageDriver](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#imageDriver) config setting to `imagick` to be sure.

> Is there a way to disable image transforms for animated GIFs or GIFs in general?

Not currently, sorry.